# Accepting paypal payments via WordPress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal

I am currently developing a WordPress plugin that allows users to accept paid guest posts. The scenario goes like this: someone visits the website of the plugin user, creates a guest post which is saved as pending and finally makes a one-time payment via paypal. Once the payment has cleared the post is published on the website.

Basically I need a solution where the website owner can specify just his or her email or merchant ID in the plugin options panel to start accepting payments.

The problem is I'm a little lost as to which paypal api to use and how to get started. There is a lot of information on the paypal website and I'm feeling a bit overwhelmed. Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is it you wanna do?
If you're just confirming the payment and let the guest author do the payment via one of the readymade PayPal buttons, you could use the Instant Payment Notification of PayPal to do that.
If you need to do more in the process, please elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using the [Express Checkout API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/) for something like that.  Specifically, you'll be using [SetExpressCheckout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/), [GetExpressCheckoutDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetExpressCheckoutDetails_API_Operation_NVP/), and [DoExpressCheckoutPayment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoExpressCheckoutPayment_API_Operation_NVP/) as explained in that first link.

My [PHP class library for PayPal](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-php-library) will make those API calls very simple for you, and you could even take a look at my [PayPal for WooCommerce](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-woocommerce) plugin to get an idea of how to use the library within a plugin if you need to.

Comment: Thanks for the links. I'll check them out.